# Ubuntu Service samba is masked and can't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i'm trying to run samba service on Ubuntu server and it gives me erros and says its masked and dead, how do i fix that ? what does cause it to be like this?

Here is the error i get:-

Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
If I'm running the Ubuntu server on Virtual box, would that be the issue? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Run `sudo systemctl unmask samba.service` and then check..

Comment: it still says it's masked

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### This is not a bug.

What you describe is intentional on the parts of the Debian people.

You are not supposed to control samba services this way on a Debian/Ubuntu systemd operating system.  You are supposed to manipulate the `smbd`, `nmbd`, and `samba-ad-dc` services as needed.

There is no umbrella `samba.target` to do the original job of the old Debian/Ubuntu `samba` van Smoorenburg `rc` script; which was starting/stopping these three en bloc.  Other people created them, for other systemd operating systems.  The Debian people did not.

So where you read Debian/Ubuntu doco saying things like

```
service samba action
```

remember that that is not an available thing any more, now that Debian Linux and Ubuntu Linux are systemd operating systems.

### Just to add to the confusion …

What the rest of the world outwith Debian knows as `samba.service` is called `samba-ad-dc.service` in the Debian world.  Similarly, `nmbd.service` and `smbd.service` are originally `nmb.service` and `smb.service` outwith Debian.

So where you read *generic* systemd operating system doco about samba talking about `nmb`, `smb`, and `samba` services, you must mentally perform the translation for Debian/Ubuntu, particularly for the latter name.

### Further reading

- Liang Guo (2014-03-06).  *[/etc/init.d/samba forbit systemd shutdown system](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740942)*.  740942.  Debian bugs.
- *[Mask /etc/init.d/samba init script for systemd](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-samba/samba.git/commit/?id=8828d90daf00d46cb95086af5e417a0701b57575)*.  Ivo De Decker.  2014-10-24.
- Ivo De Decker (2014-10-24).  *[samba init script should not be started after upgrade](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766690)*.  766690.  Debian bugs.
- Ivo De Decker (2014-11-15). *[samba: unit samba.service is masked](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=769714#10)*.  769714.  Debian bugs.
- Wulf C. Krueger (2010).  [`samba.target`](https://github.com/sunbing81/subi-exheres/blob/master/packages/net-libs/libsmbclient/files/systemd/samba.target)

Comment: so you saying i should start them individually and shouldnt worry about what samba status says?
i write >> sudo service smbd start.

and when i check it i write
 >> sudo service smbd status.
does that sound right?