# Restarting a service on Red Hat and where are the services listed

Tags: rhel, samba, services

First, I am connecting to a Red Hat machine which is identified from the following:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.2.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 (mockbuild@Build64R7) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Sep 30 15:08:55 EDT 2015
```

I had modified the /etc/samba/smb.conf to include the directory which I want to share.  In the past I would issue the following to restart the service

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

But I receive the following message

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart smbd.service
Failed to restart smbd.service: Unit not found.
```

In the past I might had looked in /etc/rc.d/init.d/ for the service, but it doesn't show the smbd service there.  I know the service is running by the following:

```
netstat -plnt | grep smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1753/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1753/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1753/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1753/smbd
```

From one of the outputs of the command I saw systemd was being used, so following some instructions from a site I tried the following (and it failed):

```
systemctl stop smbd.service      
Failed to stop smbd.service: Unit smbd.service not loaded.
```

So, now I am at a lost and my search fu has yield nothing to help me find where these services are located and how to query their status, stop/start/restart them.

Comment: You can run the following command to get a list of all loaded, active, services systemd manages: systemctl --state=active --type=service list-units

Comment: This is probably because smbd is masked. What is the status? systemctl status smbd.service

Comment: Thanks, @jdwolf, using your command to list the loaded and active service I did find out the service name is `smb.service`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong name.

What the Debian world knows as `samba-ad-dc.service` is called `samba.service` in the rest of the world outwith Debian. Similarly, `nmbd.service` and `smbd.service` are originally `nmb.service` and `smb.service` outwith Debian.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303302/5132
- https://github.com/samba-team/samba/tree/master/packaging/systemd
- https://salsa.debian.org/samba-team/samba/blob/stretch/debian/rules#L178

Comment: Using @jdwolf suggestion of querying the services I did find the service name is `smb.service` and was able to issue the command `systemctl restart smb.service` which seemed to execute without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try common process check:

```
# ps auxf | grep -2 smb
```

And from $PATH:

```
# whereis smb # or 
# whereis smbd
```

`# systemctl restart sbm` may work.