# Samba SMB Daemon fails to start; installation incomplete

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, samba, raspbian, file-server

I'm attempting to create a Samba server on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. The install gives the following error message.

```
Setting up samba (2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u1) ...
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
Job for smbd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2018-01-09 00:54:45 UTC; 503ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 27365 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 27365 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Status: "Starting process..."

Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Supervising proc…ts.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exi…ILL
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered fai…te.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with resu…p'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the result of `systemctl status smbd.service`:

```
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2018-01-09 00:54:45 UTC; 3min 17s ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 27365 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 27365 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Status: "Starting process..."

Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Supervising process 27365 which is not our child. We'll m
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Here is the relevant portion from `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit smbd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Supervising process 27365 which is not our child. We'll m
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Jan 09 00:54:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit smbd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit smbd.service has failed.
```

I'm at a loss for why this error is occurring as it's on a relatively clean installation of Raspbian and I haven't done anything experimental on it.

Comment: perhaps you just need to unmask the samba-ad-dc service?  Oh, and perhaps this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303293/ubuntu-service-samba-is-masked-and-cant-start

Comment: @GerardH.Pille trying to unmask the samba-ac-dc service is impossible as it's not installed on the system at the time of trying to unmask it. Trying to install it returns errors because it appears to be installed in a masked form. The second link regards using `service` commands rather than `systemctl`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't compare my installation to yours, I'm running Devuan on my raspberry's because of systemd.  But "service" translates normally to the corresponding systemctl command.