# Why not ssh.service but sshd.service?

Tags: ssh, systemd

When you have modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you may execute `systemctl restart sshd.service` to reflect the change. At least in my environment, also, `systemctl restart ssh.service` works. And `systemctl --all list-units ssh*` tells me there isn't any service with the name `sshd.service`. Then why is `sshd.service` used wide and actually valid?

(I know the name of ssh daemon is  `sshd` but this is not the reasonable reason, I think.)

---

I executed the following commands on `linux mint 19` (`ubuntu`-base) and `volumio 2` (`raspbian`-base), both of which are based on `debian`.

```bsh
systemctl restart sshd.service; echo $? #=> 0
systemctl restart ssh.service; echo $? #=> 0
systemctl --no-legend --all list-units ssh* #=> only ssh.service exists
```

Comment: There is no ssh.service: `Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found`, unless your distro symlinks it.

Comment: ssh is basically termed as a client, and sshd as a server... so sshd is more reasonable

Comment: You should state your distribution, Suse uses sshd.service.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Thank you. I added the distribution info.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ssh service has always been named ssh in `/etc/services`, probably whatever the distribution, because it's the *SSH* protocol, not the *`sshd`* daemon.

Then it made sense, at least in the Debian implementation and thus Debian derivatives, the same name was chosen to start the *service* as ... `service ssh start` which translated into system-V style `/etc/init.d/ssh`.

This was kept in systemd, again for consistency since the service can be started indifferently with old style or systemd-style way. Still, an alias is also defined for compatibility with other distributions which made a different choice:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

So both can be used on Debian and derivatives and they represent the same service.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the structure. As you say, I could find the alias declaration in `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`.

Answer (score 6):

As already established, different names are used in different distributions.

There are valid reasons for both

- The server is called `sshd`, therefor `sshd.service`
- `sshd` means "SSH Daemon" or "SSH Server", so "SSH Server Service" would be double.

So it would be a matter of preference of the distro maintainers. These preferences may also change over time, I remember a time when Suse switched from `ntp` to `ntpd` for the service name.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303302/5132 / https://askubuntu.com/a/856645/43344 for another commonly encountered set of differing service names.