# Why unmasking service removes the file?

Tags: systemd, services

I have

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask nmbd
Removed /etc/systemd/system/nmbd.service.

$ sudo systemctl enable nmbd
nmbd.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nmbd
```

Why? Why unmasking service removes its file? While enabling service does something strange?

Comment: This question does not state the operating system, but per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303302/5132 it is likely Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services in systemd are masked by linking an override in `/etc` to `/dev/null`; so masking `nmbd.service` is done by linking `/etc/systemd/system/nmbd.service` to `/dev/null`. Unmasking it is done by removing that link. The service file is still there, in `/lib/systemd/system/` for native systemd services.

`nmbd.service` isn’t a native systemd service, so `/lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service` doesn’t exist. It’s implemented in `/etc/init.d/nmbd`, so `systemctl` sees that and delegates to `systemd-sysv-install` to enable it. The latter delegates to the distribution-specific tool, *e.g.* `chkconfig`, `update-rc.d` etc.

Comment: Not to be confused with [`nmb.service`](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/master/packaging/systemd/nmb.service.in) of course.  (-: